# Find nodes that have more than one path to some end point

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationship, fraud-prevention

I have this relationship:

**(s)-[:ES_SOCIO_DE]->(p)-[:OFERTA_A]->(l)**

'**s**' owns '**p**' and '**p**' offers products to '**l**'

'**s**' could have more then one '**p**' and through that offers to the same '**l**'

I want to find all the cases in which '**s**' relates to '**l**' through different '**p**'

This is a graphical representation of my problem:

[image]

I want to find all this kind of relations

Is that posible?
And if it is, how can I do it?

Thanks in advance for all help that you can provide.

Comment: To clarify, you are trying to get all cases where for some given **'s'** and some **'l'**, the **'l'** is related to the **'s'** via at least two distinct **'p'**, is that correct?

Comment: @RebeccaNelson Yes!, you are right!, thanks for clarifying it!! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a query of this form:

```
MATCH (s:Socios)-[:ES_SOCIO_DE]->(p1:Proveedor)-[:OFERTA_A]->(lic)<-[:OFERTA_A]-(p2)<-[:ES_SOCIO_DE]-(s)
WHERE ID(p1) <> ID(p2)
RETURN s,lic,p1,p2;
```

That should should get you what are looking for.

If you need a different set of variables returned, substitute them in the `RETURN` clause.

Comment: Yes, that did it!